# JQuery DatePicker jumping between date/month/year when writing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want JQuery DatePicker that jumps between date/month/year fields when writing.

For example using:

```
$(function() {
  $("#date").datepicker({ 
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    constrainInput: true
  });
});
```

I want that when the user writes the (dd) for example 20 the cursor jumps to month (mm) to write the month.

Comment: Fine, we know what you want. Any attempts so far?

Comment: I tried searching in the API doc: https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/ but no option seems what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

jQuery DatePicker using `<input type="text">`.

If you will find the way to change that input into type data it will jump between fields.

```js
const dateInput = document.getElementById('dateInput');
    
dateInput.onclick = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
};
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="dateInput" type="date">
</form>
```

Comment: Ah ok it seemms to work but what happens with the default HTML5 input date calendar?

Comment: We can use preventDefault build-in js function for it, but I need to install datePicker to check everything or you can try to play with it for now, if not I will help you then.